# Как указать пакету django-registration использовать кастомную форму регистрации?

Tags: python, django

Я делаю регистрацию и авторизацию пользователя с помощью пакета `django-registration`. Мне нужно было сделать так, чтобы емейлы у пользователей были уникальными и поэтому я сделал кастомную модель пользователя, переопределив только поле емейла:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        _('email address'),
        unique=True,
    )
```

В настройках я соответственно указал эту модель:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'shop.User'
```

Теперь, когда я хочу зайти на страницу регистрации, у меня возникает такая ошибка:

```
_ImproperlyConfigured at /accounts/register/
You are attempting to use the registration view <class 'django_registration.backends.activation.views.RegistrationView'>
with the form class <class 'django_registration.forms.RegistrationForm'>,
but the model used by that form (<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>) is not
your Django installation's user model (<class 'shop.models.User'>).

Most often this occurs because you are using a custom user model, but
forgot to specify a custom registration form class for it. Specifying
a custom registration form class is required when using a custom user
model. Please see django-registration's documentation on custom user
models for more details._
```

Она говорит, что модель в классе `Meta` формы `RegistrationForm` и модель, прописанная в настройках, различны.

Чтобы решить данную проблему, я решил переопределить `RegistrationForm`:

```py
CustomUser = get_user_model()


class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    class Meta(RegistrationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
```

Но теперь я не знаю, как мне указать чтобы `django-registration` использовал эту форму для регистрации пользователей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного внимательнее почитав документацию я нашел ответ - нужно просто написать в маршрутах проекта вот етот код:

```
from django_registration.backends.activation.views import RegistrationView
from mycustomuserapp.forms import MyCustomUserForm
...
...
path('accounts/register/',
        RegistrationView.as_view(
            form_class=MyCustomUserForm
        ),
        name='django_registration_register',
    ),
```

а уже все остальние маршрути пакета django-registration должни идти после етого маршрута.